# Supervisorctl : Issuing in running supervistorctl status

Tags: python, docker, supervisord

I am not able to run any `supervisorctl` command inside docker container like `stop`, `start`, `status`, `restart`, etc.

My Supervisord configuration looks like below

```
abc@abc-adhocworker-c89d9667b-9lqbd:/app$ cat worker.conf 
[supervisord]
logfile=/dev/null
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true

[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:worker]
command=./manage.py rq worker %(ENV_QUEUES)s
process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
numprocs=%(ENV_WORKERS_COUNT)s
directory=/app
stopsignal=TERM
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=300
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[eventlistener:worker_healthcheck]
autorestart=true
serverurl=AUTO
command=./manage.py rq healthcheck
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
events=TICK_60
```

Got this error

```
Error: .ini file does not include supervisorctl section
For help, use /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -h
```

I tried adding in above configuration

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
```

Then getting an error while running the supervisorctl status

```
abc@abc-adhocworker-c89d9667b-9lqbd:/app$ /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl status
error: <class 'OSError'>, [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address: file: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py line: 716
```

Also tried changing it to

```
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
```

Not sure after changing the configuration we need to restart/reload supervisord ?

Note : I am running these commands inside docker container.

Comment: Rather than trying to restart individual processes (especially if it's the main container process) it's usually better to delete and recreate the container.  Can you run multiple containers (maybe from the same image) rather than using supervisord?

Answer (score 0):

### Run the supervisorctl status

- Execute using `exec`
- Also specifying `supervisord` configuration with `-c`

```
abc@abc-adhocworker-c89d9667b-9lqbd:/app$ exec supervisorctl -c worker.conf status
worker:worker-0                  STARTING  
worker:worker-1                  FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
worker_healthcheck               RUNNING   pid 14, uptime 7:49:44
```

### Make sure to add `supervisorctl` section

with `serverurl` with location of socket file in your `supervisord.conf`(In my case it was named `worker.conf`)

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
```

#### References

https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/376#issuecomment-404385767